# How to get Api-key from mobile files?

Tags: android, firebase, api, apk, api-key

I'm currently playing a game on my phone and I'd like to "play around" with it a little (don't worry it's all agreed with the developer and he's allowed me to change the files and other stuff if I don't sell it or tweak it online).
I'm currently looking for the api key of the game in the files that the game has on my phone.
The game is on google firebase and my phone is rooted.
I've already found the databaseURL or the appid or a few other tokens.
But I can't find the API key...
Is there a scheme where you can find the best?
In the package there are these subfolders:
app_pccache
app_sslcache
app_textures
app_tmppcache
app_webview
cache
code_cache
databases
files
no_backup
shard_preferences
In shard preferences are only xml files (all decrypted)
in no_backup there are 3 databases
These are all folders that I found with the rooted cell phone.
I found this with a non-rooted by extracting this and looking in:
assets (folders)
google (folder)
Kotlin (folder)
lib (folder)
Meta info (folder)
re (folder)
And some individual files but only with the property’s (versions)
I use the MT manager

Comment: API-keys are usually included in the APK. Decompiled the APK using `apktool` and then search the files for the key.

Comment: "the API key" is a bit vague in the context of an app that uses Firebase as it uses multiple configuration values to identify the Firebase project, based on the Firebase products it uses. While one of those configuration values is called API key, multiple others serve the exact same purpose. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: i have all infos like appid and databaseurl only thing that is missing is tzhe api key...